# Styling `django-social-widgets` buttons

Tags: html, css, django

I included the following two buttons to share the content in twitter and facebook respectively.

```
{% social_widget_render "twitter/share_button.html" href=request.build_absolute_uri %}
{% social_widget_render "facebook/share_button.html" href=request.build_absolute_uri  data-layout="button_count" %}
```

and it looks like:

[image]

I inspect it and could only fix the margin and positioning but couldn't fix the background color, removing the social icons adding my own custom texts.

```
#twitter-widget-0 {
  margin-top: 10px !important;
}
.fb_iframe_widget {
  span {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    margin-top: -0.5rem;
  }
}
```

How to add or remove custom icons of it. Further, add custom texts like instead of share text for facebook share, I can replace it with `share on facebook`, or style the button to look like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just guessing here, but what happens if you change the path, instead of `twitter/share_button.html` you put your own template ?

Comment: That comes to mind first, but I couldn't manipulate the content, please leave an answer if you could. here is github link of this widget https://github.com/creafz/django-social-widgets/

Comment: Yes I went to see the github page and the doc but it's a rather small project, without a lot of users. You'll have a better chance getting an answer by creating an issue on github I think.

Comment: yes, it is small but best for social widgets. I will try that also. Thank you brother